# Is there any module to sell a page access?

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, access

Is there any module that allows the admin **to sell a page access**?

In some **e-shops**, we refer to this feature as content **access selling** or **pay per reading**.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I have found is Drupal Commerce Kickstart which is a distribution of Drupal that includes Drupal Commerce and a wide variety of contributed modules. The distribution provide selling access to digital content on your site out of the box.